# VS Code and Python import - relative/absolute path problem

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I know, that there are already threads open that discuss this topic, but NONE helped so far.

My project in VS Code looks like this:

```
    /myproject    
        main.py
        /sub1
             __init__.py
             sub1_mod1.py
            /sub1_1
                 __init__.py
                 sub1_1_mod1.py
            /sub1_2
                 __init__.py
                 sub1_2_mod1.py
        /sub2
             __init__.py
             sub1_mod1.py
            /sub2_1
                 __init__.py
                 sub2_1_mod1.py
            /sub2_2
                 __init__.py
                 sub2_2_mod1.py
```

In VS Code the path of /myproject is ... ofc ... set as the project.

Code like

```
    # main.py absolute imports
    from sub1 import sub1_mod1 as sub1_mod1
    from sub1.sub1_1 import sub1_1_mod1 as sub1_1_mod1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        sub1_mod1.sub1_mod1_def1()
        sub1_1_mod1.sub1_1_mod1_def1()
```

works like a charm. But what i want is: **Imports between packages: e.g. import /sub1/sub1_mod1.py in /sub2/sub2_mod.py**. I am using this code:

```
    # sub2_mod1.py
    import sub1.sub1_mod1 as sub1_mod1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        sub1_mod1.sub1_mod1_def1()
```

VS Code shows no errors, auto completes everything (e.g. when typing sub1_mod1. ... i get all functions and can select sub1_mod1_def1()). But the moment i run the code i get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub1'**

I also tried to work with all the VS Code/Pylance options:

```
   "python.analysis.importFormat": "relative" 
   - - - - - - - - - - - - OR - - - - - - - - - - - -
   "python.analysis.importFormat": "absolute"

   ...

   "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true
   - - - - - - - - - - - - OR - - - - - - - - - - - -
   "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": false

   ...

       "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/sub1",
        "/sub2",
        "/sub1/sub1_1",
        "/sub1/sub1_2",
        "/sub2/sub2_1",
        "/sub2/sub2_2"
    ]
    - - - - - - - - - - - - OR - - - - - - - - - - - -
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": []
```

None of the options changed a thing.

TL;DNR: Going deeper in in the (current) path is no problem. However, going in the other direction does not work. Any clues on how to set this up? Oh and I prefer a solution without import os and stay "native".

Comment: VsCode didn't give an error because it doesn't know in which file to run the interpreter, if you run the file "main.py", there will be no error, even though it imports /sub1/sub1_mod1.py into /sub2/sub2_mod.py. This is because python takes the path of the executed file ("main.py"), therefore all imports must respect this path.

Comment: TBH i only understand parts of this and i may lack a very basic information. However, ignoring the main.py for a moment, there must be a way of using modules from a different package (no matter if i run any module in a package or the main.py). This is working when using import sys and adding a path by sys.path.insert(...). But this is currently a nogo for serveral reasons.

Comment: Every time you do "import", python will take the path of the executed file. For example: if you run sub2, python will use the path myproject/main.py/sub2, then it will see that you want to import sub1.sub1_mod1, so it will look for it in the path I save, but it will fail because myproject/main.py/sub2/sub1 /sub1_mod1.py does not exist.

This is because python imports use your relative path not absolute, if you want to use absolute just use os.

I hope I explained myself well =D

Answer (score 0):

I create the similar directory structure and I get the same problem.

Usually, the default setting about the current folder it the project folder (We can search "Terminal: Execute In File Dir" and find it's not checked).

However, it still gives error moduleNotFound even if the file dir is correct. I submit the problem to [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20472).

Here is an interim solution, we can use [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension and use **Run Code** to run python file:

[image]

It is the code-runner that runs normally makes me think it is a bug.